# Disk corrupted while formatting, no machine recognises it anymore

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive

So I have a Seagate SRD00F2 3TB external harddrive that I wanted to format from HFS to NTFS. I did this in Win10 via Disk Manager. It started, hanged after a while, then crashed, and now my HD isn't recognized by any machine (tried an Ubuntu machine, Win10 and OSX).

It's clear something on the drive got corrupted, but I have no clue how to fix it. I've googled around on how to fix corrupted drives but all solutions either
- Depend on it showing up in various CLI disk interfaces (it doesn't)
- Are some worthless trash articles aimed to get you to download some malware infested recovery app to fix your problem (and tried some of those, none recognized the disk either)

Now thankfully I had already backed up the drive so I have no fear of data loss, but it is a good drive when it's working and I don't want to give up on it just yet.

So, how to fix an unrecognized/corrupted drive without having to worry about data recovery? Is there anything I can do?

Edit:

- In Win10 using `DiskPart`'s `list disk` command doesn't list the drive
- In Ubuntu `lsusb -v` doesn't list it
- In Ubuntu, `dmesg` shows

  ```
   [33546.486264] usb 2-1: new SuperSpeed Gen 1 USB device number 7 using xhci_hcd
   [33551.746088] usb 2-1: device descriptor read/8, error -110
  ```

That `dmesg` output gives something to work with!

Comment: Have you tried Seagate's [SeaTools for Windows](https://www.seagate.com/gb/en/support/downloads/seatools/#), with the disk drive connected to the computer with a SATA cable? It is possible for the USB to SATA adapter in the enclosure to fail.

Comment: Yep, tried all of those; it also doesn't pick up the drive sadly :/

Comment: Does the disk drive make the normal disk drive starting up sound or is it silent or perhaps clicky?

Comment: @AndrewMorton; there is no hardware issue; it doesn't make weird sounds or anything; didn't take any damage too. The fault is clearly software based when it failed to format (or that process damaged the hardware?)

@KamilMaciorowski; updated!

Comment: Remove the disc from the case and test it connecting to computer via SATA cable.

Comment: @Akina OP says they have tried that (see the first two comments).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never got the external drive recognized. I mailed with Seagate about the issue and they also told me to take the drive out of the casing, and attach it with a SATA cable. Turns out I had a faulty SATA cable, because at a later time it did pick up the drive. The partitioning was all screwed up, so I wiped them all, reformatted to NFTS and the drive worked great inside my pc.

Took it out, reinserted it into the external casing, but that still wouldn't work. I figure the chip in the external casing would be dead/corrupted and I'm alright with using the drive internally instead. 
I think it should work if I'd get another external casing, but it's unnecessary for me now.